# TypeError is not a function - val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that this question has been asked a lot but I can't seem to find an answer I am looking for. I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).hasClass(...).val is not a function
at attach_selectors (commercial.js:768)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (commercial.js:117)
at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
```

I understand it has something to do with the val() but if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great. Do I need to create a new function?

```css
var stInput=$("form").find("input").hasClass("st-search").val();
$("#submitSearch").off("click").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".gsc-search-button").find(stInput).click();
}

);
```

```html
<form class="st-search">
  <div class="gcse-search"><input type="text" class="st-default-search-input" placeholder="Search..." />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary-bel gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2" id="submitSearch" title="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Run the following in your browser: `console.log($("form").find("input").hasClass("st-search"))` and see what it returns

Comment: so doing console.log($("form.st-search").find("input").val()); seems to print out the right value however, my button doesn't click

Comment: well if you read the value outside of the click, you get the value when it runs. It is not a reference that auto updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasClass` returns either `true` or `false` which doesn't have a `val` function. Perhaps you want to adjust your selector to `$('form.st-search')`?

Comment: thanks! this let me get the right information, now i need to figure out why my button won't click :)

Answer (score 2):

**This line returns a boolean rather than a jQuery object**

```
var stInput = $("form").find("input").hasClass("st-search");
```

**Probably you want to do this:**

```
var stInput = $("form").find("input").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

`.hasClass` returns true or false. [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/).

It seems like what you want is this:

```
var stInput = $("form input.st-search").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Added snippet and removed `hasClass()` as this function returns a boolean value.

```js
var stInput = $("form").find("input").val();

$("#submitSearch").off("click").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Update value
    stInput = $("form").find("input").val()
    console.log(stInput);

    $(".gsc-search-button").find(stInput).click();
  }

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="st-search">
  <div class="gcse-search"><input type="text" class="st-default-search-input" placeholder="Search..." />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary-bel gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2" id="submitSearch" title="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

hasClass() function returns only boolean value.

```
var data = $("form").find("input").val();
```

```js
var stInput = $(".st-default-search-input").val();

$("#submitSearch").off("click").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".gsc-search-button").find(stInput).click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="st-search"><div class="gcse-search"><input type="text" class="st-default-search-input" placeholder="Search..." /><xsl:text> </xsl:text></div>
<button class="btn btn-secondary-bel gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2" id="submitSearch" title="search">Search</button>
</form>
```